# Is it possible prevent styles from "hitching up" direct formatting?

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment, typesetting, paragraph-styles, formatting

Here is a simple test:

1. Create a new document and a text frame
2. Type

   ```
   | three                  |
   |                        |
   | lines                  |
   |                        |
   | of text                |
   ```
3. Change the alignment of the second line to the right, so that now you have

   ```
   | three                  |
   |                        |
   |                  lines |
   |                        |
   | of text                |
   ```
4. Change the alignment of the Basic Paragraph style to to the right, so that now you have

   ```
   |                  three |
   |                        |
   |                  lines |
   |                        |
   |                of text |
   ```
5. Change the alignment of the Basic Paragraph style back to the left. Notice that now all the three lines, including the second line, have changed their alignment.

   ```
   | three                  |
   |                        |
   | lines                  |
   |                        |
   | of text                |
   ```

   ... while I have expected that the second line, because it was aligned manually, will stay on the right side.

Is there a way to prevent it from moving, apart from creating an additional paragraph style for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style overrides **are** maintained when merely *applying* styles.

The issue with your example is that the style has been **redefined** *twice* - once to align everything right, *negating* the manual override since it now **matches** the style definition, then again to align everything left.

You've essentially overwritten the manual formatting by redefining the style to *match* the override, then redefining the style *again*.

Styles really *shouldn't* be redefined repeatedly. 
That's kind of the point of having styles.

In the question example, I would use **two** styles - one left aligned and one right aligned.

Or, learn to *not* repeatedly *redefine* styles containing these sort of aspects (alignment) once they are set. Simply *don't* change unique items such as alignment when redefining a style.

You *can* change universal aspects such as typeface, size, etc. and redefining won't change the manual alignment override. If the alignment defined in the style *doesn't* change when redefining, then the manual alignment override also *won't* change.

---

Random tip...

For 99.9% of all InDesign documents, I strongly recommend one **NEVER** relies on or uses the [Basic Paragraph] style.

If you need a style, define a *new style* - as opposed to altering the [Basic Paragraph] style.

You'll find, eventually, using the [Basic Paragraph] style becomes *exceptionally* problematic if you ever need to copy/paste or otherwise move content from one document to another, or give the document to someone with a *different* system and INDD installation. Because *their* [Basic Paragraph] defaults *won't* match your [Basic Paragraph] defaults.

Using *unique* style names can prevent a considerable amount of headaches in the future. The [Basic Paragraph] style is *reset* to its defaults with *each* and *every* new InDesign document.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott. I use CS6 on Windows. Did I understand you correctly that, for example, InDesign CC 2017 on Mac might have different settings for Basic Paragraph?

Comment: @johnc.j. **Every** installation of InDesign will have the factory defaults for [Basic Paragraph]. While they can be changed, most often they are not. Trust me, you just don't want to use [Basic Paragraph]. It's a minor thing to create a new style and use that. But fixing things after [Basic Paragraph] has overridden your style can be much more labor intensive - especially if you have manual overrides within the applicable paragraphs.

Comment: When *unique* style names conflict, the user is *asked* which style to use. When [Basic Paragraph] conflicts, there's no asking, INDD simply uses the default settings - completely wiping out any custom alterations you've made to the style.

Comment: It's also wise to not create new styles which are *based* on [Basic Paragraph] for similar reasons. Although being based on [Basic Paragraph] isn't as often a problem as using the actual style can be.

Comment: _"When unique style names conflict, the user is asked which style to use."_ - Could you elaborate in which exact cirumstances I will be asked about this? I have just tried to create two documents with the "foo" paragraph style in both. In the first document, its color is blue. In the second, it is red. When I copy a small frame with text with the "foo" style from the first document to the second, its color is simply silently changes (to red); InDesign doesn't ask me anything.

Comment: I mistyped.... when pasting the *existing* style in the document being pasted to takes precedence. Therefore, pasting something with [Basic Paragraph] means you *reset* the paste to the default [Basic Paragraph] in the open document. (I must've been thinking of Word imports for the "asking" bit - it's Word Style conflicts which ask the user.)

Answer (score 2):

An override is no longer an override, once you make edits to the style that are identical to the edits in the override (your step 4 above).

At which point you just make another edit to the style, which affects all the lines (your step 5 above).

So yes, you need to create an additional paragraph style to keep that organized left and right.

However, in some cases, where there is not much repetition of styles in a document, it makes sense to just break the links to every style to avoid confusion, and just manually custom format each text frame, without linking it to actual Paragraph Styles.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by _breaking the links to every style_? :-)

Comment: Paragraph Styles panel, flyout menu, there's an option called BREAK LINK TO STYLE. Read the documentation if you're not familiar with what this does.

Comment: https://creativepro.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/default/files/story_images_3/20130618-styles11.png

Comment: Great tip, thanks!